# wordpress admin widget reorder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have being toying with rearranging the order of the admin widgets in the dashboard with no luck- i need my own custom widget at the top.... Wordpress's own method for doing this (http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) simply doesnt work...

Anybody have any working ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: the method to reorder widgets given in the official WP page (url above) - tried it multiple time and it just doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because there is a call to `usort()` at line 23 in `includes/widgets.php` that uses `strnatcasecmp()` for comparisons. There is no obvious way to override or change this call.

One possible workaround would be to do a little hackery that removes your widget from `$wp_registered_widgets` and then re-inserts it with a name that begins with a space, thereby putting it at the top of the sort order. Note: I have not tried doing this, and there may be other things that break using this approach, but there aren't a whole lot of other options short of hacking the core file itself, which is a Bad Thing®.

Ps: Since the sort takes a string arg, I have one nasty thought involving an on-the-fly search and replace in the core code itself ... nah, that would involve Flying Monkey Patching™, which means Flying Monkeys, and you know what happened to Dorothy. Better to not go there.